# In Visual Studio Code a folder with files are getting deleted after some time

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am a new user of Visual Studio Code. The problem is when I create a folder for files, it gets deleted after a while. I have had this problem 4 times. Tried to solve it by resetting VSCode, but the issue persists.

Here is an example and a screenshot

```
Unable to open 'lesson_5.html': Unable to read file 'd:\Microsoft VS Code\study\lesson_5.html' (Error: Unable to resolve nonexistent file 'd:\Microsoft VS Code\study\lesson_5.html').
```

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zp8vl.png)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you have deleted or renamed that file locally, however, VSCode still thinks there is such a file. But when trying to access it faces a problem, because there is no reference to such a file. Try refreshing your IDE and check if your files are where they are supposed to be.

Comment: i refreshed vs studio code by following next algorithm: 1) open the command palette with View > Command Palette... (or Shift+Cmd+P on OS X) 2) type "reload window" and press enter. but it still doesn't work. the problem is that whole folder with files mysticly deleted sometimes, and all files don't open. This problem has come 4 times, and i still can't get how to solve it =(

Comment: Well, I'm no Doctor Strange :D. Can't really help you, need more details. If you can't figure out why the files are being deleted, then I would suggest reinstallation. That usually helps))

Comment: i also reinstalled it, but it's the same problem =(

Comment: if it persists after reinstallation, it means the index was't deleted (no clean deinstallation), you have to find the folder where VSCode puts its data and find/remove there.

Answer (score 0):

I think I've had the same bug. Bugging me for almost a week. After opening one it figures that it's missing and gets removed from the index.

Renaming the already from VSCode removed folder has no effect either.

**Workaround:**

I ended up filtering by the old path name in the VSCode file menu (cmd+p Mac) klicked like a maniac about 100 times the 'x' to remove the ghost entries, done!

Took me about 30s, if you have 500+ files I suggest further investigation

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue where files were getting deleted from my project and hundreds of duplicate files were appearing in my editor out of nowhere. But I believe I know what was causing it.

1. My folder was tracked by iCloud/OneDrive.
2. The folder was uploaded to the cloud
3. I deleted the project folder locally
4. I created a new project with the same name
5. The cloud tries to sync the changes so files start appearing/deleting

The solution is to move all your projects to a location not being uploaded to the cloud and use something like GitHub to store your code.